# How can we use .wsdl file from local drive to send soap request?

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I am new to soap web services. I have local wsdl file. The company I want to connect to ...com?wsdl url has closed for security reasons. I need to reach locally. When I use the soap ui tool and send a request, a successful result is returned. but when I send a request with the help of soap package with nodejs, the result is returned. The methods appear in the client.describe method. but I can't access the methods. Please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88GsU.png)

Answer (score 1):

> WSDL (web service description language) is an XML notation for
> describing a web service. A WSDL definition tells a client how to
> compose a web service request and describes the interface that is
> provided by the web service provider.
>
> Typically a WSDL definition is divided into separate sections that
> specify the logical interface and the physical details of a web
> service. The physical details include both endpoint information, such
> as HTTP port number, and binding information, which specifies how the
> SOAP payload is represented and which transport is used.

Because the company closed the endpoint for security reasons, I assume that you changed it successfully to a local URI in the `.wsdl` file.

With node.js, you should be able to query it with or without a specific node package, since soap services can be queried with HTTP POST, a few extra headers and an XML SOAP envelope. Otherwise here is an example that you can adapt with easy SOAP request:

```
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const fs = require('fs');`enter code here`

// example data
const url = 'http://your-local-ip:80/test';
const sampleHeaders = {
  'user-agent': 'sampleTest',
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  'soapAction': 'http://your-local-ip:80/test/yourservice.wsdl#Test',
};
const xml = fs.readFileSync('./someEnvelope.xml', 'utf-8');

// usage of module
(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest({ url: url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml: xml, timeout: 1000 }); // Optional timeout parameter(milliseconds)
  const { headers, body, statusCode } = response;
  console.log(headers);
  console.log(body);
  console.log(statusCode);
})();
```